# Load jQuery script in jQuery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

First post.

I have searched extensively for a clear cut answer, however I am more stuck than ever after reading for hours.

What I am trying to accomplish: 
I would like to be able to load a javascript live search script for 1 page (page1) on a multi page app. The search filters li items in a ul

What I have learned:
I have come to the conclusion after much searching that I cannot use document.ready and instead must bind it to pageinit.

```
$('#page1').live('pageinit', function () {
$("#filter").keyup(function () {

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val();

    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".list li,h2").each(function () {

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
});
```

I have tried to alter my conditioning statements and I cannot find a solution.

Here is what I have thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/zb0t/L9t7G/

P.S. I have also tried simply adding jQuery mobiles data-filter="true" however, I could not figure out how to embed the search field into the header as it would simply stay fixed under the header and I could not call the data-mini="true".

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: fixed http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L9t7G/1/

Comment: Follow up question: Where should I embed this code in a jQuery mobile site? In the head tag it does not fire and neither at the end in the body tag. Thanks in advanced

Comment: In head if you're using single page template. If you're using multi file, place it inside page div.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick response. I have put the <script> in the page div however it still won't fire. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: With `pageinit` event wrapping the code?

Comment: I have embedded your suggestion from your Jsfiddle directly under the page div but it still doesn't work. Thank you for all of your help so far!

Comment: If that page is the first one, place it in head.

Comment: I will continue to try. My apologies for the hassle. I have 4 pages right now and when I add it under the page div it doesn't fire.

Comment: If you have all pages in one file, place it in hide. Make sure to give the div which contains the listview filter an id. And bind pageinit to it as in my demo

Comment: So far no luck still. I will continue to play with it.

Comment: do you have page with id `page1`?

Comment: here's a better version http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7R9Z7/

Comment: Thanks Omar. I have changed my approach for now mainly for my sanity so I flush out the rest of my content. I have simply added data-filter="true" to the ul and jquery mobile adds a fixed search bar that does the filtering without the fade out effect. I will ultimately have three pages (#page2, #page3, #page4) that I would like to benefit from the search

Comment: Side question for you Omar. I am now having trouble ridding my app of the flicker when slide transitioning. I have tried to substitute jquery transitions for different frameworks but, similar to my struggles with the search, I am wondering if my head tag is congested and not set in proper order. How could I assure I disable jquery transitions and enable another external js and css? If too much no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

jQuery 1.9 does not have [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), that was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9